# Cygwin alternative for OSX pbcopy?

Tags: osx, clipboard

Is there a Cygwin alternative for OS X's `pbcopy`?

From [Mac Developer Library man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pbcopy.1.html)

```
pbcopy, pbpaste - provide copying and pasting to the pasteboard (the Clipboard) 
from command line
```

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. What is `pbcopy`? What features must your "alternative" have? There are people who might know exactly what you want – but cannot tell you because they don't know they know (not knowing `pbcopy`) ;) Please [edit] your post and specify.

Comment: I've upvoted every answer here. good work, people.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently Cygwin has `/dev/clipboard`, so you can do stuff like `echo test >/dev/clipboard`.

See also [Fun with Cygwin's /dev/clipboard](http://williammitchell.blogspot.de/2008/03/fun-with-cygwins-devclipboard.html)

Comment: +1.  "Fun with Cygwin's /dev/clipboard" was also well worth reading.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft Windows has a native solution that you can also use in Cygwin: `clip`. For example:

`systeminfo | clip`

Further details: [Microsoft TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754731(v=ws.11).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I've got the following in my `~/.bash_profile`, which essentially adds OS X's `pbcopy` and `pbpaste` to Cygwin:

```
if [ -e /dev/clipboard ]; then        
    alias pbcopy='cat >/dev/clipboard'
    alias pbpaste='cat /dev/clipboard'
fi
```